# Show video in collection view cell

Tags: uicollectionview, avplayer, avasset, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to show multiple videos in a collection view. I have this code:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return array.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Path"];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = NO;
    playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    [cell insertSubview:playerViewController.view atIndex:0];

    [player play];

    return cell;

}
```

But the code is very slowly and the scrolling is not smooth. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have sample code that does exactly what you want, and more. You can download the code and see a video showing what it does from/at:

http://demonicactivity.blogspot.com/2016/08/draft-what-in-hell-this-demoniac-is-up.html